# Why can't you add value to <p></p>?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I notice that these two lines of code

```js
$('<button class="test" value="Hello">Test</button>').appendTo('#body');
console.log("The button is " + $(".test").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body"></div>
```

will give you the value of Hello, yet this same format of code

```js
$('<p class="test" value="Hello">Test</p>').appendTo('#body');
console.log("The p is " + $(".test").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body"></div>
```

will give you blank. Does .val() not work with p elements and only with buttons?

Comment: It's not valid HTML. The HTML spec does not define a `value` attribute on the `p` element. You can still get the value using `attr("value")`, if you must, but it has no meaning and would be confusing to later programmers who stumble upon your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain paragraph is not one of the HTML elements that can have the `value` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

However, you can put `data` attributes on anything you want, use that instead of `value`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*

Answer (score 0):

It will woks only for form elements. Please check:
https://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp
The value attribute can be used in these elements:

```
<button>
<input> 
<meter> 
<li>    
<option>    
<progress>
<param>
```